# Thoughts on migrating Answer from duplicate question to original question?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I've spent probably two hours finely crafting an answer here: ([Bandwidth Monitoring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844270/bandwidth-monitoring/844317#844317))

However the question I'm answering is being flagged (with 2 close votes) as a duplicate of this Q&A: ([How to track the total network data in a month](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15836/how-to-track-the-total-data-transfered-in-a-month))

What would the ethics / morals be of taking my answer from the close candidate and repeating it in the duplicate target?

My feeling is once the duplicate candidate is closed people will skip my elbow-greased answer and go to the original Q&A instead. My temptation is to copy and paste my answer from the duplicate thread to the original thread.

Of course I feel my answer in the duplicate candidate is better than any in the original thread.

Your profound insights are appreciated in advance :)

Comment: A mod might be able to move the answer.

Comment: I am upvoting this because more people should be asking for this when they answer dupes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where a merge comes in :)

Cast your close vote and use a custom flag to ask for the two questions to be merged.

Comment: Thank you Seth :)

Comment: It appears the question merged into: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15836/how-to-track-the-total-data-transfered-in-a-month/844317#844317, has been flagged as a duplicate of this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage/846455#846455. Strangely the duplicate flag is 4 1/2 years old? I copied my answer over to the new original thread...